# How to fix GattStatus: 3 - WriteNotPermitted exception for BLE Xamarin forms application?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I am working on a BLE application. I am able to connect to MI band and get the services through my Xamarin forms BLE app. But when I am trying to write characteristics I am getting exception. I'm getting exception

> Characteristic does not support write.

for the method `WriteAsync()`. This is my code where I am writing to characteristics:

```
private async Task<string> ProcessDeviceInformationService(IService deviceInfoService)
    {
        try
        {
           await adapter.ConnectToDeviceAsync(device);
            var sb = new StringBuilder("Getting information from Device Information service: \n");
            var characteristics = await deviceInfoService.GetCharacteristicsAsync();
            var characteristic = await deviceInfoService.GetCharacteristicAsync(Guid.Parse("00002A27-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
           // characteristic.CanWrite = true;
            //foreach (var characteristic in characteristics)
            //{
                try
                {
                   // await Task.Delay(300);
                    var bytes = await characteristic.ReadAsync();
                    var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, 0);
                    ManufacturerLabel.Text = str;
                    //var characteristic = await deviceInfoService.GetCharacteristicAsync(GattCharacteristicIdentifiers.DataExchange);
                    if (characteristic != null)
                    {
                        byte[] senddata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.IsNullOrEmpty(SendMessageLabel.Text) ? "jenx.si was here" : SendMessageLabel.Text);
                        await Task.Delay(300);
                        var newbytes = await characteristic.WriteAsync(senddata);
                        var strnew = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(senddata, 0, 0);
                        ManufacturerLabel.Text = newbytes.ToString();
                        //var strnew = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newbytes, 0, 0);
                    }
                   
                   // ManufacturerLabel.Text = str;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return ex.Message;
                }
            //}

            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

I have no clue how to fix this any suggestions?

Comment: You read/write are backwards.  You want to read the characteristics from the BLE and write results to a byte array.  You are writing the characteristics from a byte array.

Comment: @jdweng can u explain it through code. Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: Following is writing to controlCharacteristic.  You want to read.: controlCharacteristic.WriteAsync(new byte[]
                    {COMMAND_BYTE, COMMAND_HEART_RATE_CONTINUOUS, COMMAND_ON});

Comment: @jdweng I'm reading the characterics aswell before writing it to byte array. I'm editing my post u can look into it.

Comment: See code on following page.  The Write parameter is an enumeration (not a byte array) : https://github.com/jeroendesloovere/examples-windows/blob/master/Bluetooth%20Generic%20Attribute%20Profile%20-%20Heart%20Rate%20Service/C%23/Shared/HeartRateService.cs

Comment: @jdweng That project is for windows will it work for android?

Comment: @jdweng do u know any xamarin project where it is used?

Comment: Visual Studio 4.7.2 and later you can write the same c# code for both Windows (Net) and Android/Xamarin (Core) and you can target the code for either Net or Core.  The source code doesn't change.   In some cases Core is a compact version of Net and doesn't include all the libraries.  When a library doesn't exist you may need to add a Github library if one exists.  The source doesn't usually have to change if the library is available in both Core and Net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this. First of all **we need to check if the Characteristic has the write operation** in it for that you can download an app called **BLE scanner** from play store and connect to that device. When we connect to that BLE we will be able to see the available services and characteristics of the BLE Peripheral. **And there we need to check which characteristics has write operation**. So if you try to do write characteristics for characteristics which doesn't have a write operation in peripheral it will give **exception write not permitted**.